# Centering Toast Message in Android

Tags: android

Ok, I feel like I've tried every configuration possible, but I can't seem to position my Toast message in the center of the screen of my Android application. It keeps showing up in the default position, near the bottom of the screen.

This is the code I'm currently using but, again I've tried a lot of different configurations. Any ideas?

```
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Please Set a Profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
   toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setGravity` works on all versions below `R`. It has been discontinued from the `R`. Check this in the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int)

> Warning: Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, for apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher, this method is a no-op when called on text toasts.

So, either you target a lower version or you can find other options like creating a custom view that behaves like a toast.

Comment: Thanks very much! Good to know. Think I'm just going to use AlertDialogs, will work better for this purpose anyway.

Comment: Sure. Android recommends Snackbar 

If your app is in the foreground, consider using a snackbar instead of using a toast. Snackbars include user-actionable options, which can provide a better app experience.

If your app is in the background, and you want users to take some action, use a notification instead.
-----
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#alternatives

Comment: Got it, ok I'll look into Snackbar as well. Thanks for the advice!